# Python generator doesnot working with Keras

Tags: python, keras, generator

I have the problem with generator `Python`. When creating a generator to train with Keras, I want to have different value every time. However, even using the lock, I only get the same value during the `epoch`. Does `Keras` use generator difference?

```
        def image_generator_for_filter_language_chinese(self):
        while True:
            with self.counter_lock:
                *local_count = self.globals_count
                self.globals_count += 1*
            print("count_batch", local_count, ", ", self.numb_sample)
            local_count %= self.batch_per_epoch
            with self.lmdb_keys_lock:
                batch_list = self.lmdb_keys[int(local_count * self.batch_size):
                                            int(min((local_count + 1) * self.batch_size, self.numb_samples_data))]


            batch_lmdb_keys = np.random.RandomState().choice(a=batch_list, size=self.batch_size)
            batch_x, batch_y = self.get_data_from_lmdb(batch_lmdb_keys, True)

            if local_count == 0:
                with self.lmdb_keys_lock:
                    random.shuffle(self.lmdb_keys)

            yield (batch_x, batch_y)
```

Using `keras`

```
model.fit_generator(
        train_gen.image_generator_for_filter_language_chinese(),
        verbose=1,
        steps_per_epoch=40000/batch_size,
        epochs=nb_epochs,
        use_multiprocessing=True,
        validation_data=val_gen.image_generator_for_filter_language_chinese(),
        validation_steps=10000/128,
        workers=num_thread,
        callbacks=cbs)
```

I get the result

```
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 13 ,  250
count_batch 13 ,  250
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 14 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 16 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 15 ,  250
count_batch 16 ,  250
count_batch 16 ,  250
count_batch 16 ,  250
count_batch 16 ,  250
count_batch 16 ,  250
count_batch 16 ,  250
count_batch 16 ,  250
count_batch 17 ,  250
```

Why the `count_batch` doesn't change as I want?
This approach work perfect if I use single thread, but multi-thread doesnot work as I expect.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is your batch_size value?

Comment: My batch_size is 128. I think the problem not related to batch_size. The only problem is the count_batch face race condition even I use lock.

Comment: steps_per_epoch must be an integer. so you might want to do ceil(40000/batch_size)

Comment: It doesnot work. Results still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using multi processing mechanism can solve problem.

```
from multiprocessing import Value

globals_count = Value(ctypes.c_int, int(0))
def __get_count(self):
        tmp = self.globals_count.value
        with self.globals_count.get_lock():
            self.globals_count.value += 1
        return tmp
```

It work perfect now. The problem was Keras use multiprocessing while I only use multithreading lock to handle.

Answer (score -2):

```
import stdio
import sys
from markov_model import MarkovModel
def main()
```

hints:

- read command-line arguments k and s
- intitialize text to text read from standard input using sys.stdin.read()
- create a Markov model model using text and k
- use model.replace_unknown() to decode the corrupted text s
- write the decoded text to standard output
- Implemt the method replace_unknown() in MarkModel using the idea suggested on the following slide